# AWS ioredis with node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ioredis

I have to connect with a redis cluster which is in AWS. Can anyone guide how to connect to redis cluster using ioredis and node js. There will be one master and 3 slaves.
Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by reading the documentation: ["Access Patterns for Accessing an ElastiCache Cluster in an Amazon VPC"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/elasticache-vpc-accessing.html)

As you can see in the doc your solution will depend if running within the same VPC or not.

Once your connectivity problem is solved you can move to the [ioredis documentation](https://github.com/luin/ioredis), you can see a very straightforward example in there.

```
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

redis.set('foo', 'bar');
redis.get('foo', function (err, result) {
  console.log(result);
});

// Or using a promise if the last argument isn't a function
redis.get('foo').then(function (result) {
  console.log(result);
});

// Arguments to commands are flattened, so the following are the same:
redis.sadd('set', 1, 3, 5, 7);
redis.sadd('set', [1, 3, 5, 7]);

// All arguments are passed directly to the redis server:
redis.set('key', 100, 'EX', 10);
```